# correct file structure for mvc (servlets,jsp,web.xml)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, web.xml

I am writing a simple mvc application called **FirstApp**.The file structure for the project is as follows:

```
FirstApp
|--entername.html
|--WEB-INF
    |--web.xml
    |--classes
          |--web
             |--EnterName.class
          |--model
```

When i try to run it on the tomcat server,it gives me a HTTP 500 error.
[image: HTTP 500 ERROR]
My deployment descriptor is correct is correct as far as i know.

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <display-name>Welcome to first servlet</display-name>
  <description>
     Welcome to My first servlet on linux
  </description>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>first servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>web.EnterName</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>first servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Enter.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

EnterName.java file

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class EnterName extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        pw.println("hello how are you ");
    }
}
```

What's causing the error?There are no files in the **model** folder as of now

Comment: What's the source code of EnterName.java? How do you deploy the app?

Comment: @JBNizet The above structure is present in the **apache-tomcat-7.0.67/webapps/FirstApp** direcotory

Comment: And what is the source code of EnterName.java?

Comment: @JBNizet just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is not in the `web` package as you claim it is in the `web.xml` file, and in the directory structure.

Add

```
package web;
```

as the very first line of the class.

The directory structure under `WEB-INF/classes` must match exactly with the package structure. The class is named `web.EnterName` only if its actual package is `web`, and its simple name is `EnterName`.

Comment: Yes.Rather silly of me.This works.
What if i don't use `package web`  in my java file and in the **web.xml** file use only `<servlet-class>EnterName</servlet-class>` It's not working

Comment: The default package should NEVER be used. It's one of the things that Java should have disallowed from the beginning. Just never use it. That said, I think it should work in this case, provided you put the EnterName.class file directly under WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Yup.Got it.It works when put under `classes` folder.